Capacitance for power factor correction formula
I wrote a test the other day and the paper provided a formula for calculating the required capacitance needed for power factor correction. The formula:
\begin{align}
C = \frac{Q_c}{\omega V_{RMS}^2} \space\space [1]
\end{align}
This was never stated in the textbook. This is my guess on how they got it. These formulas are all from the textbook we use.
\begin{align}
C = \frac {1}{\omega X} \space\space [2] \\\\
Q = Im(\pmb S) = I_{RMS}^2 X \space\space [3]
\end{align}
So you can assume from normal DC power that (this is not in the textbook):
\begin{align}
Q = \frac{V_{RMS}^2}{X} \space\space [4]
\end{align}
This is then substituted in the second equation to get the formula provided in the test. I tried to verify with equation 3 with equation 4, but they did not yield the same answer. The textbook derived equation 3 in the following way (Bold indicates phasors or complex numbers and * the conjugate):
\begin{align}
\pmb S = \pmb V_{RMS} \pmb I_{RMS}^* \space\space [5]\\\\
\pmb Z = \frac {\pmb V_{RMS}}{\pmb I_{RMS}} = \frac{V_{RMS}}{I_{RMS}} \angle \theta_{v} - \theta_{i} \space\space [6]\\ 
\pmb I_{RMS} = \frac{\pmb V_{RMS}}{\pmb Z} \space\space [7]\\\\
\pmb S = I_{RMS}^2 \pmb Z = \frac{V_{RMS}^2}{\pmb Z^*} \space\space [8]
\end{align}
The get the imaginary part of the complex power using voltage and impedance we need the conjugate of the impedance, which means the real part of the impedance has an effect.
The following is derived from equation 8:
\begin{align}
Q = \frac{V_{RMS}^2X}{R^2+X^2}
\end{align}
R is the real part of the impedance and X is the complex part. Finding a formula for X in terms of VRMS and Q will result in a quadratic equation, not equation 4. I derived the following equation for the capacitance needed for power factor correction:
\begin{align}
C = \frac{I_{RMS}}{\omega V_{RMS}\sin(\theta_{v}-\theta_{i})}
\end{align}
This gave the same result as when I used equation 3 with 2 and the total impedance afterwards had no complex part which was not the case for equation 1 that was derived(I guess) from equation 4. I am still only studying, therefor I asked this question to see if I am correct. Can someone please confirm that equation 4 and 1 is wrong?

You wrote this beautifully - it should be an email to your professor. You can use overleaf to easily write it in latex without a local install if that’d make it easier.
